# Dynamically hide/display Jenkins parameters based on the previously selected parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

It would be great if you can provide me the solution for the below problem in Jenkins build with parameters.

Problem : I have a parameter with dropdown values "Yes" and "No" in Jenkins Job.

If user selects "Yes", display two String parameters "ABC" and "XYZ" to allow the user to provide the values for the parameters

If user selects "No", Don't display the String parameters.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This is something I've been wondering for some time myself. I'm not sure if Jenkins currently has any capability to dynamically change what parameters are available.